# Jackson throwing nosuchmethod error while

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-mvc, jackson

I have following class which i am returning from spring rest server

```
public class Message {
    private String name;
    private String text;

    public Message(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

And I am getting following error when i try to access the api

```
g.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

here is my jackson mapping tree via `mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson`

```
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
```

and here is my actual jackson dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried including latest version of both libraries. I am not sure what i am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Spring version are you using?
Check out the library requirements for Spring on [the Spring wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework).

If you're using Spring 4+, you don't need `org.codehaus` dependencies.

Now there are some issues with Jackson 2.7 - this version will be supported in Spring 4.3 (see [SPR-13728](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13728) and [SPR-13483](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13483)). In the meantime, you should stick to Jackson 2.6+.

Comment: Thanks. that helped.